# Fade effect refresh on lost focus mutiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to web development and I love it.

But I've have encountered a problem and I can't figure it out. 
When i lose my focus on my browser tab, my fade effect ,made for my images when they are change, is turns on multiple times. .

Another problem, i really want my images inside of my div element to be like : http://jsfiddle.net/eb51hxj1/  when i resize the browser.

```
 <div class="divImage">
    <img id="image"> </div>
 <div>
```

My code is :

https://jsfiddle.net/a2bsarfb/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a new var that checks for the window focus. When the window focus is gone then just skip the rest of the code.

At the very top add a new var:

```
var lostFocus = false;
```

In the Caller function add:

```
if(lostFocus){ return false; }
```

So it will look like:

```
function Caller() {
  var imag = ["https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tq0H6nQMdNk/maxresdefault.jpg", "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/4qVMnkF7W60/maxresdefault.jpg", "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/52/1d/e6/521de6a52e774664745132156448f43b.jpg"];
  var numarImagini = imag.length - 1;
  var i = Math.floor((Math.random() * imag.length));
  Rotate(imag[i], i);
  i++;
  setInterval(function() {
    if(lostFocus){ return false; }
    if (i > imag.length - 1) {
      i = 0;
      Rotate(imag[i], i);
      i++;
    } else {
      Rotate(imag[i], i);
      i++;
    }
  }, 2000)
}
```

And at the bottom add the event listeners:

```
window.onblur = function() { lostFocus = true; };
window.onfocus = function() { lostFocus = false; };
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answear. This is what i was looking to achieve !